# How can I divide a string into parts in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code below I just need to divide the string into parts in the onSelect parameter of auto complete function

```
$(function(){
    $('#business_category').autoComplete({
        minChars: 2,
        source: function(term, response){
            term = term.toLowerCase();
            var countryName = $("select[name=country]").val();
            var data_search_term = $("input[name=business_category]").val();
            console.log(countryName);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/businesses_search_terms_count.php",
                data: "countryName=" + countryName + "&searchTerm=" + data_search_term,
                dataType: "json",

                success: function(resp){
                    response(resp.data)                
                }
            });
        },
        onSelect: function(event, term, item) {
            console.log("searchedItem: " + term);
            var data_search_term = $("input[name=business_category]").val();
            $('#total-count').html(data_search_term);                   
        }
    });
});
```

---

Right now, when user selects any category my output is: `(Audio and video => 6,488)`. But I want an output like this: `(Audio and video)`. So I just want a string with the category field not with count number like => 6,488

Comment: First of it's really unclear what part of all your code you need to split, second what is the desired result?

Comment: Can you please show us how the expected result should be?

Comment: Divide string into parts?  Do you mean like using  a band saw to cut it up?

Comment: update expected output. it is still unclear

Comment: Which string? How do you define the "parts"?  By space?  By comma?  By character?  By characters 1-5, 6-8, 9-15, 16-300? (etc)  It's nice that you've provided some code, but none of it is relevant to the question.  Provide an example input, the expected output and what you've tried to achieve that.

Comment: I have a category field on front end page when user select any category then string must be in category field and count number should be show below

Comment: @JawadAltaf It's still not clear what you want and from where and how it should be splitted, You HAVE to provide us an example.

Comment: My out put is (Audio and video => 6,488) but i want out put like this (Audio and video) when user select any category

Comment: jQuery has no ability to manipulate strings

Comment: It seems to me that you should solve your problem (not using js) but in ajax/businesses_search_terms_count.php or/and your database query. Could you provide this server-side code (php...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Donny stated, you can achieve it with pure Javascript. My solution is very similar to his but I just wanted to share a little bit more concise solution using template strings:

```js
const str = "(Audio and video => 6,488)";  
console.log(`${str.split("=>")[0].trim()})`);
```

Comment: This is a nice one liner solution!

Comment: @f-CJ Thanks a lot sir for this answer

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal using pure JavaScript with string.split() and string.trim()

```
  var str = "(Audio and video => 6,488)";
  var res = str.split("=>")[0]; //Turn string into array splitting by '=>' and get the first element
  res = res.trim(); //Remove side spaces
  res += ')'; //add ')' to the end of the string
  console.log(res); //prints to console '(Audio and video)'
```

Comment: You're welcome ^_^
Please consider marking my answer so it can help other people who are having the same issue

Comment: sir now i have another field which name is select country so now i want that when user select another country then the string autometic reset or empty from category field. totally i have two field country field and category field. so finally do you have any solution?

Comment: Please open a different question in which you describe the problem with details